# Como tratar um valor de uma função como uma variável já existente?

Tags: python, funções, pygame

Eu estou fazendo um simples jogo, somente para testar a biblioteca PyGame. Acontece que como no jogo eu teria diversos objetos eu achei mais viável criar uma função para move-los:

```
def mover(objeto,direcao,velocidade):
if direcao == 'dir':
    objeto = (objeto + int(velocidade))
if direcao == 'esq':
    objeto = (objeto - int(velocidade))
if direcao == 'cima':
    objeto = (objeto - int(velocidade))
if direcao == 'baixo':
    objeto = (objeto + int(velocidade))
```

Onde "objeto" é onde coloco a variável que guarda a posição do objeto que estou me referindo.

Criei uma bolinha e pra guardar sua posição criei a variável "y_bola", e pra move-la eu simplesmente aumento, ou diminuo esse valor. O problema é que quando eu coloco "y_bola" na função "mover" ela pega o valor de "y_bola" e não a variável em si.

**Queria saber como atualizar o valor da variável (y_bola) dentro da função.**

Aqui segue o código inteiro:

````
import pygame, time
pygame.init()

# Configurando a janela
tela = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Meu Jogo!')

# Preparando para inciar
jogando = True
 #configurando cores
branco = (255,255,255)
preto = (0,0,0)
vermelho = (255,0,0)
verde = (0,255,0)
azul = (0,0,255)
 #valores incicias
y_bola = (1890)
direcao = True

# Funções e procedimentos
def mover(objeto,direcao,velocidade):
    if direcao == 'dir':
        objeto = (objeto + int(velocidade))
    if direcao == 'esq':
        objeto = (objeto - int(velocidade))
    if direcao == 'cima':
        objeto = (objeto - int(velocidade))
    if direcao == 'baixo':
        objeto = (objeto + int(velocidade))

# Iniciando
while jogando == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            jogando = False
    
    # Desenhando atores e objetos
    tela.fill(branco)
     #bola subindo
    if direcao == True:
        y_bola = (y_bola - 7)
        cor = (azul)
        if y_bola < 50:
            direcao = False
            cor = (vermelho)
     #bola descendo
    else:
        y_bola = (y_bola + 17)
        if y_bola > 1870:
            direcao = True
    pygame.draw.circle(tela,cor,(550,y_bola),70)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()```
````

Answer (score 0):

A solução ideal seria criar um objeto para armazenar a posição e outros atributos das bolas, por exemplo:

```py
VERMELHO = (255, 0, 0,)

class Bola:
    def __init__(self, x, y, tamanho, cor):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tamanho = tamanho
        self.cor = cor
```

Daí você pode criá-la usando algo como:

```py
bola = Bola(0, 0, 50, VERMELHO)
```

Para acessar os valores "lá de dentro" como `bola.x`, `bola.y`, `bola.tamanho` e `bola.cor`, por exemplo:

```py
>>> print(bola.x)
0
>>> bola.y = 100
```

Daí a rotina de movimentação poderia ser colocada no laço principal (lá dentro do `while`):

```py
    CIMA = 1
    BAIXO = 2
    PASSO = 5

    ALTURA = 500
    LARGURA = 500

    DIRECAO = random.choice([CIMA, BAIXO])

    tela = pygame.display.set_mode((LARGURA, ALTURA))

    while True:
        ...
        if direcao == CIMA:
            bola.y -= PASSO
            if bola.y < 0:
                direcao = BAIXO
        elif direcao == BAIXO:
            bola.y += PASSO
            if bola.y > ALTURA:
                direcao = CIMA
        ...
        pygame.draw.circle(tela, bola.cor, (bola.x, bola.y), bola.tamanho)
```

Ou mesmo colocar esta rotina em uma função que retorne os novos valores de X e Y para o objeto.

E para não deixar a resposta muito longa, preparei uma [versão](https://gist.github.com/plainspooky/cf7a5ecdc095f54fe18b2a1900d5ef5c) completa e comentada deste código.